# validate where each parent intermediary is also a parent to itself

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to validate where each parent intermediary is also a parent to itself. So this query should return invalid parents in SELECT If table has any.

I need to do is first of all get all parents records. This should be done by joining Intermediries to itself on ParentIntermediaryID = IntermediaryID (inner join). Now, from all the parents return those parents that don't have any rows with ParentIntermediaryID = IntermediaryID.

I hopa the requirement is clear. Can you give me query for this?

--===== Create the test table

```
CREATE TABLE Intermediary
    (
    IntermediaryPK INT ,
    IntermediaryID NVARCHAR(20),
    IntermediaryName NVARCHAR(200),
    IntermediaryTypeID NVARCHAR(1),
    ParentIntermediaryID NVARCHAR(20),
    IntermediaryTypePK TINYINT,
    ParentIntermediaryPK INT
    GrandParentIntermediaryPK INT
    GrandParentIntermediaryID NVARCHAR(20)
    )
```

== Insert the test data into the test table

```
INSERT INTO Intermediary
   (IntermediaryPK, IntermediaryID, IntermediaryName, IntermediaryTypeID, ParentIntermediaryID,
    IntermediaryTypePK, ParentIntermediaryPK, GrandParentIntermediaryPK, GrandParentIntermediaryID)
SELECT 552, '200244584261', 'A', '1', '201841943403', 1, 6459, 6459, '201841943403' UNION ALL
SELECT 553, '200983879092', 'B', '1', '200707895681', 1, 6462, 6459, '200707895681' UNION ALL
SELECT 554, '200925413387', 'C', '1', '200707895681', 1, 6462, 6462, '200707895681' UNION ALL
SELECT 555, '200472620781', 'D', '1', '200707895681', 1, 6462, 6462, '200707895681' UNION ALL
SELECT 556, '201902784325', 'E', '1', '200707895681', 1, 6462, 6462, '200707895681' UNION ALL
SELECT 557, '201874832909', 'F', '1', '200707895681', 1, 566 , 6462, '200707895681' UNION ALL
SELECT 558, '201264024229', 'G', '1', '200707895681', 1, 566 , 6462, '200707895681' UNION ALL
SELECT 559, '201725870455', 'H', '1', '201062751762', 1, 566 , 6462, '200707895681'
```

I have tried with this query:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    Intermediary AS I1 
WHERE   ParentIntermediaryPK IS NOT NULL 
AND     NOT EXISTS ( 
            SELECT  * 
            FROM    Intermediary AS I2 
            WHERE   I2.IntermediaryPK = I2.ParentIntermediaryPK 
            AND I1.ParentIntermediaryPK = I2.IntermediaryPK )
```

Comment: I want to write a query which will validate each parent intermediary is also a parent to itself. So this query should return invalid parents in SELECT If table has any.

Comment: Well, you've restated your intention, thanks for that. But you haven't answered either of my questions. I'll be fair with you and repeat them as well: 1. What have you *already* tried? 2. What *exactly* is difficult for you at this point? What are you struggling with? Honestly, so far your question reads basically like this: "I want to do this thing but I don't know how to and so I won't do it. Please someone do that thing for me." I don't think this can attract many helping hands.

Comment: Hi Andriy
            I have tried with this query:

SELECT *
FROM Intermediary AS I1 
WHERE ParentIntermediaryPK IS NOT NULL
AND NOT EXISTS
  (
   SELECT *
   FROM Intermediary AS I2 
   WHERE I2.IntermediaryPK = I2.ParentIntermediaryPK
   AND I1.ParentIntermediaryPK = I2.IntermediaryPK
  )

Comment: Thank you! But please update your question instead of just replying to me. (Use the Edit link underneath it.) My point was that your question didn't sound well enough to attract any help, and by updating your question with what you have tried you will at the very least be letting the people know that you are not being lazy. Also, to help you to improve your question further, please elaborate (in your question) on which rows in your example should be returned by the query you are trying to build, and why. That's just to make sure the goal is clear. (I, for one, am not sure I've understood all.)

Comment: For example we have

Intermediaries       ParentIntermediaries

A   F
B   A
C
D   C
E   D 
F   B

Suppose If C has child and It does not have any parents, So C itself should have its parents or else C should be null.... So we have to validate like this....

Comment: I have edited your previous question. This should stay closed.

Answer (score 0):

The naming convention here is what gave me trouble the last time you posed this question. But basically you just want to return all values where ParentIntermediaryPK isn't null, and doesn't match the value of IntermediaryPK on the same row?

If I understood that right, it would be this simple?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Intermediary 
WHERE IntermediaryPK <> ParentIntermediaryPK 
AND IntermediaryPK IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hi Kahn,
For example we have

Intermediaries       ParentIntermediaries

A   F
B   A
C
D   C
E   D 
F   B

Suppose If C has child and It does not have any parents, So C itself should have its parents or else C should be null.... So we have to validate like this....

Comment: I need to do is first of all get all parents records. This should be done by joining Intermediries to itself on ParentIntermediaryID = IntermediaryID (inner join)
Now, from all the parents return those parents that don't have any rows with ParentIntermediaryID = IntermediaryID.

Comment: I have written this query, And this query returns all parents that are at the top of the hierarchy. No parents of Their own. But my validation should return all parents that don't have the link to themselves...
What correction I can make in this query?

SELECT * FROM Intermediaries I1 INNER JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT ParentIntermediaryID
FROM Intermediaries 
WHERE IntermediaryID = ParentIntermediaryID
) I2
ON I1.IntermediaryID = I2.ParentIntermediaryID 
AND I1.ParentIntermediaryID IS NULL

Thanks for your time..